# convert <select> to <input radio>

Tags: html, forms, select

Confused about how to convert my `<select><option>` into radio buttons.

After spending days setting up this dropdown menu to function correctly in this simpleCart(js) project, now my client (to my great joy) has change his mind and has decided that he wants buttons instead.

What would be the correct way of implementing this change. I have tried radio buttons but what I have done so far does not work. The form I've made does not seem to communicate with the simpleCart(js).

What I had (working perfectly)

```
<select id="sizeSelect" class="item_size dropdown" autocomplete="off">
    <option value="nul" selected="selected">Please choose size</option>
    <option value="Small">Small</option>
    <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="Large">Large</option>
    <option value="Super Brain">Super Brain</option>
    </select>

    <select id="shippingSelect" class="item_shipping" autocomplete="off">
    <option value="nul" selected="selected">Please choose shipping</option>
    <option value="ups">UPS Standard 25€</option>
    <option value="mail">Standard Mail 10€</option>
    </select>
    <select id="regionSelect" class="item_tax" autocomplete="off">
    <option value="nul" selected="selected">Please choose region</option>
    <option value="Eu VAT 21%">Eu VAT 21%</option>
    <option value="World (Taxfree)">World (Tax Free)</option>
    </select>

<button class="item_add">Add to Cart</button>
```

What I am trying (not working)

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Please choose size:</legend>
<input type="radio" name="size" id"sizeSelect" class="item_size" value="nul" style="display:none" checked>  
<label><input type="radio" name="size" id"sizeSelect" class="item_size" value="small"> Small </label>
<label><input type="radio" name="size" id"sizeSelect" class="item_size" value="medium"> Medium </label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Please choose shipping:</legend>
<input type="radio" name="shipping" id="shippingSelect" class"item_shipping" value="nul" style="display:none" checked>
<label><input type="radio" name="shipping" id="shippingSelect" class"item_shipping" value="ups"> UPS Standard 25€</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="shipping" id="shippingSelect" class"item_shipping" value="mail"> Standard Mail 10€</label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Please choose destination:</legend>
<input type="radio" name="destination" id="destinationSelect" class"item_price" value="nul" style="display:none" checked>
<label><input type="radio" name="destination" id="destinationSelect" class"item_price" value="290.00"> EU</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="destination" id="destinationSelect" class"item_price" value="220.00"> World</label>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" class="item_add " value="Add to Cart">
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

Using the  it is enough to use `class="item_size` or other SC classes to feed the data to the cart.

**UPDATE**

Cart HTML:

```
    <div class="simpleCart_items"></div>
    <div class="simpleCart_itemSize"></div>
    Shipping:<span class="simpleCart_shipping"></span><br> 
    <strong>Total with Shipping: <span class="simpleCart_grandTotal"></span></strong>
    <p style="text-align:right"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_checkout">Checkout</a></p>
```

Using radio buttons I get a Grandtotal of

> Total with Shipping: €NaN

so it is aparent that the form is not comunicationg with the cart.. . but where the plug is loose is a total mystery for me..

**UPDATE**
Sorry guys, in my frustation I forgot to put this...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    simpleCart.shipping = function(){
    if( $("#shippingSelect").val() == "nul" ){return 0;}    
    if( $("#shippingSelect").val() == "ups" ){return 25;}
    if( $("#shippingSelect").val() == "mail" ){return 10;}
    };
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    simpleCart.tax = function(){
    if( $("#regionSelect").val() == "nul" ){return 0;}  
    if( $("#regionSelect").val() == "Eu VAT 21%" ){return 90;}
    if( $("#regionSelect").val() == "World (Taxfree)" ){return 0;}
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is really your problem? Seems okay.. How do you get the data in $_POST?

Comment: Please let us know what error/exception you are getting

Comment: in my browser error console I do not get any errors. :(

Comment: whats generating that error message?

Comment: Liam, the cart is not able to calculate the sum of 'item_shipping' or 'item_price'

Comment: What's the cart? How's it trying to *calculate the sum*? Your giving us half a picture here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setting your values to `functions` not to values. The below:

```
simpleCart.tax = function(){
    if( $("#regionSelect").val() == "nul" ){return 0;}  
    if( $("#regionSelect").val() == "Eu VAT 21%" ){return 90;}
    if( $("#regionSelect").val() == "World (Taxfree)" ){return 0;}
    };
```

does not set `tax` to the `return` value it set's it to a [function pointer](http://owen.sj.ca.us/~rk/howto/javascript/funcptr.html). Which, because it isn't a number (it's a `function`) is `Nan`.

change this to:

```
function getTax(){
        if( $("#regionSelect").val() == "nul" ){return 0;}  
        if( $("#regionSelect").val() == "Eu VAT 21%" ){return 90;}
        if( $("#regionSelect").val() == "World (Taxfree)" ){return 0;}
        }

simpleCart.tax =  getTax();
```

to further explain it you could do this:

```
function getTax(){
        if( $("#regionSelect").val() == "nul" ){return 0;}  
        if( $("#regionSelect").val() == "Eu VAT 21%" ){return 90;}
        if( $("#regionSelect").val() == "World (Taxfree)" ){return 0;}
        }
//this is a function pointer
var getTaxFunctionpointer = getTax;

//this will return an integer
simpleCart.tax =  getTaxFunctionpointer();
```